# How can we create custom style for Jquery-ui dialog window in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-ui, drupal-6

I am having a PHP page which the result table contain a link that opens a popup box. Earlier I used JavaScript. But I want to hide the address bar, so this cant be done in JavaScript(hope so). So I tried using jQuery-ui for this.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<style type="text/css">
    #data-specs {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    #data-specs th,
    #data-specs td {
        padding: 0px;
        border: 0px;
    }
    .loading {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -8px;
        margin-left: -8px;
    }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $loading = $('<img src="loading.gif" alt="loading" class="loading">');

            $('#data-specs a').each(function() {
                var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                    .append($loading.clone());
                var $link = $(this).one('click', function() {
                    $dialog
                        .load($link.attr('href'))
                        .dialog({
                            title: 'Dialog Title',
                            width: 500,
                            height: 300
                        });

                    $link.click(function() {
                        $dialog.dialog('open');

                        return false;
                    });

                    return false;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

My table part code is like this:

```
print "<table width='875' id='data-specs' align='center'>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
              print "<tr height='18'>";
              print "<td width=200 align=left style='padding-left:10px'>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>";
              print "<td width=70 align=center>" . $row['MidEstimate'] . "</td>";
              print "<td width=70 align=center>" . $row['LowEstimate'] . "</td>";
              print "<td width=70 align=center>" . $row['HighEstimate'] . "</td>";
              print "<td width=118 align=center>" . $row['Source'] . "</td>";
              print "<td width=110 align=center>" . $row['StudyLocation'] . "</td>";
              print "<td width=89 align=center>" . $row['Relevance'] . "</td>";
              print "<td width=89 align=center>" . $row['Quality'] . "</td>";

print "<td width=61><a style='color:#E46D0A;' href='popupboxD.php?SId=$vv'>".$row['Info']."</a></td>";
              print "</tr>";

         }
        }

if(empty($result)){

print "<table width='875' align='center'>";
print "<tr height='1'><td colspan='9'><font color='#000080'><b>Does not have information on this particular selection.</b></font></td></tr>";
print "</table>";
```

Now the problem is its all works well. But when I click the link, the jQuery dialog box opens and the style(css) for my parent window is also changing? I want the style to be applied only for dialog window also I want to change the look and feel of dialog window? How can I do this? please help me in this.

### Update

I am using this code in drupal 6, but when I click the link the pop-up is not opening as a modal dialog window. IT opens completely in the parent window? How can I in-corporate jQuery UI in drupal 6 with same code? Please help me.

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tHEh9/) with your code. Can you update it, so we can see where your problems are?

Comment: the code in the jsfiddle is correct, while the dialog window opens style in the parent window is also changing ? also I want to change the look and feel of dialog window (eg. changing the title bar color or padding contents in ...like that) . anything else need please let me know ? thanx for helping.. Is it possible to use a custom style sheet rather than this(<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">) in above code ? IF possible how to start with ?

Comment: One more issue I found is for first time the dialog window is coming as specified in script once it is closed and open again its not keeping its width and hieght specified inscript ?

Comment: The same is working in drupal... I miss placed the needed files in the drupal site folder.. sorry... also I installed the jquery ui, jquery ui dialog module in drupal 6 ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your own jQuery ui styling (a theme), make your changes on [jquery ui themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller). After that you can download it (before you should deselect all components), if it's a zip decompress it, save the files on your server and replace the `href` attribute of you following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

But this will change all jQuery ui elements of this page.

=== UPDATE ===

To make the dialog modal you have to add the [modal option](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#option-modal).

```
.dialog({
    ...
    modal: true
})
```

Also see my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tHEh9/1/).

Comment: I use jquery ui themeroller to create css for my needs. thank you very much for the help....

Comment: one more thing, I got inline css in the external page which opens as jquery ui modal window, some css are not working like. for **td** I had put **style='border:0;padding-right:5;padding-top:5'** but **bgcolor='#CECFFF'** is working ? could you please help me to sort this out ?

Comment: Try following: `style='border:0;padding-right:5px;padding-top:5px'`

Answer (score 1):

In general, PHP has nothing to do with JQuery, Javascript, HTML controls and all that stuff.

PHP is merely a text processor. It is **your** job to determine, **what text** to output. PHP won't do it for you.

Once you done with text - then you can print it out with PHP. It is not a big deal too - there are simple formatting rules for the PHP strings.

However, to output large amounts of texts. you can just escape from PHP:

```
<?
//some PHP
?>
<table width='875' align='center'>
  <tr height='1'>
    <td colspan='9'>
      <font color='#000080'>
        <b>Does not have information on this particular selection.</b>
      </font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?
//PHP again
?>
```